# How to replace every item in a list except last

Tags: python, list

I have a few lists such as `[1,3,5,2], [2,3], [5,3,2,5]` and so on. I want to make it so they are modified to hide every number except the last, such as `[x,x,x,2],[x,3],[x,x,x,5]`. I tried something like:

```
lists = [[1,3,5,2],[2,3],[5,3,2,5]]
for list in lists:
    new_list = [ i = 'x' for i in list[:-1]]
```

Comment: `I tried` and what was the result?

Comment: Usual Comment: Don't use `list` as variable as it shadows the builtin. Surprisingly none of the answers have mentioned it (Include high rep holders)

Comment: @BhargavRao What do you mean by shadows the builtin?

Comment: `list` is a predefined function in python that is used to convert iterables to lists. Thus if you use `list` as a keyword, you will be losing the functionality of the built-in function `list`

Comment: ohhh! i see what you mean. Yeah, i don't have that in my code, just this example for sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for l in lists:
    l[:-1] = ['x'] * (len(l) - 1)
```

Comment: you don't need to put `x` inside a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last element by `[-1]` index and then create a list of `X` then add to last element :

```
>>> [[['X' for _ in li[:-1]]+[li[-1]]]for li in lists]
[[['X', 'X', 'X', 2]], [['X', 3]], [['X', 'X', 'X', 5]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

may be

```
>>> [['x'  for _ in L[:-1]] + [L[-1]] for L in lists]
[['x', 'x', 'x', 2], ['x', 3], ['x', 'x', 'x', 5]]
```

or better as suggested by [Shashank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2653390/):

```
>>> [['x'  for _ in L[:-1]] + L[-1:] for L in lists]
[['x', 'x', 'x', 2], ['x', 3], ['x', 'x', 'x', 5]]
```

Comment: One alternate way of doing [List[-1]] would be List[-1:].

Comment: @Shashank thanks Shashank, I would like to improve my answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
lists = [[1,3,5,2],[2,3],[5,3,2,5]]
lists = [list('x'*(len(l)-1) + str(l[-1])) for l in lists]
# OUT: [['x', 'x', 'x', '2'], ['x', '3'], ['x', 'x', 'x', '5']]
```

Note that this converts the last number in each list into a string, which may or may not be what you want.